# Cannot connect to a specific game's servers without VPN

Tags: vpn, nat

I cannot connect to Rainbow Six Siege servers without VPN. This issue started recently and I am 100% sure that it is isn't because of some changed settings in my PC or router. I can connect to other online video game servers but this specific game keeps giving me errors when I do not use a VPN.

I researched Reddit and Rainbow Six Siege forums, and people recently seem to be experiencing connectivity issues but I am still not sure it is related to Rainbow Six Siege.

I am sure VPN does not put me in a different region because I can manually choose which region I can connect.

One person suggest that the problem might stem from NAT, for example a strict NAT type but I am not sure how I can change NAT type.

What sort of a problem (either on game servers or on my PC) can cause this type of problem any why is a VPN fixing it?

Comment: It could even just be because of your public IP (whether it's dedicated or not) got blocked...

Comment: VPN will route you to different servers/entry points, even if you are picking the same region. If you pick a New York VPN, you're going to get into Microsoft/Ubisoft's network through an entry point near New York.

Comment: @Andy No, that is not the case. I can see which region I am connecting to. I can connect to whatever region I want to when I am using a VPN.